# Update libinput on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, libinput

In my synaptic paket manager I find libinput-bin version 1.6.3 installed. [Here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/) on their homepage I saw that the newest version is 1.9.3.

I'd like to use the newest version as it includes some changes on swipe/pinch detection for touchpads. Is it possible to easily install the newest version of libinput?

My linux knowledge is very basic so I don't know how this all works together (I'm aware that it might be risky to install such things too early but I like to experiment :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to install the sid (unstable) [debian package (1.9.3)](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libinput-bin).

Download the [deb file](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libinput/libinput-bin_1.9.3-1_amd64.deb) and install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i libinput-bin_1.9.3-1_amd64.deb
```

You will probably need to also install some dependencies using the same way.

WARNING : This a good mean to obtain an unstable system. But if you want to experiment...

Comment: The important package here is [`libinput10`](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/libinput10), but the principle stays the same.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! :) I installed version 1.9.2 (buster) instead as it is stated as "not so unstable" as 1.9.3. Now my 3 finger swipe is recognized correctly with libinput-gestures :)
@StephenKitt what is the difference between 10 and bin?

Comment: See the package descriptions: `libinput-bin` contains the `udev` rules, `libinput10` contains the library (which is where the implementation lives). If all you needed were quirk updates, updating the `udev` rules would be sufficient, otherwise you’d need to update `libinput10`.